# SSLContext certificate chain not populated into context

Tags: java, authentication, certificate

Please help to understand how to provide chain of certificates to SSL Context.

Intro:
I'm using EWSJavaAPI 1.2 to connect to ms exchange.
It used TLS connection with two-way authentication, based on my own certificate issued by my company signed by my-CA derived from my-root-cert. All these entities exist but i use only PFX.

I init SLLcontext with one PFX key and use TRUST-ALL implementaiton for trust manager.

My project dependencies:

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <classifier>adapters</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>EWSJavaAPI</groupId>

          <artifactId>EWSJavaAPI</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
```

My sample to connect:

```
package mail.msexchangetest;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedEvent;
import javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedListener;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ClientCertificateCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EmailMessage;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Folder;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.FolderId;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Mailbox;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MessageBody;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceLocalException;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WellKnownFolderName;

\/**
 * 
 *
 *\/
public class App \{


    private static TrustManagerFactory tmf;
    private static SSLContext ctx ;

    private static TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager(){
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String    authType){
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){
            }
        }};
        // The trust all certs.

        private static void setSSLConfigManual() throws Exception 
        {

            KeyStore ks=KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("/home/user/Documents/private/mail-cert/compUser.pfx"),"mypass".toCharArray());

            System.out.println("init Stores...");

            KeyManagerFactory kmf=KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks,"mypass".toCharArray());

            ctx= SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

            SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

        }



    public static void main( String[] args ) throws URISyntaxException, Exception
    {

        setSSLConfigManual();

        System.out.println("=============BEGIN HANDSHAKE=============");
        testConnect();
        System.out.print(">");
        System.in.read();
        System.out.println("=============END HANDSHAKE=============");

        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        System.out.println("=============BEGIN EXCHANGE_2007 MESSAGE SEND=============");
        try{
            send2007Message();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("=============ERROR EXCHANGE_2007 MESSAGE SEND=============");
            System.out.print(">");
            System.in.read();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print(">");
            System.in.read();
        }
        System.out.println("=============END EXCHANGE_2007 MESSAGE SEND=============");

        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        System.out.println("=============BEGIN EXCHANGE_2010 MESSAGE SEND=============");
        try{
            send2010Message();            
        } catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("=============ERROR EXCHANGE_2010 MESSAGE SEND=============");        
            System.out.print(">");
            System.in.read();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print(">");
            System.in.read();
        }
        System.out.println("=============END EXCHANGE_2010 MESSAGE SEND=============");        

    }

    private static void send2010Message() throws ServiceLocalException, Exception, URISyntaxException {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);


        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(
                                                "username",
                                                "userpass","DOMAIN");
        service.setCredentials(credentials);

        service.setTraceEnabled(true);        
        service.setUrl(new URI("https://mail.server.country/"));

        service.setTimeout(100*1000);


        Folder myFolder = new Folder(service);
        myFolder.setDisplayName("My EWS Test Folder");
        FolderId rootFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, new Mailbox("user@server.country" ));
        myFolder.save(rootFolderId);

        EmailMessage msg= new EmailMessage(service);
        msg.setSubject("Test message "+System.currentTimeMillis()); 
        msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Sent using the EWS Managed API."));
        msg.getToRecipients().add("User@gmail.com");

        msg.send();
    }

    private static void send2007Message() throws ServiceLocalException, Exception, URISyntaxException {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(
                                                "user",
                                                "pass","DOMAIN");
        service.setCredentials(credentials);

        service.setTraceEnabled(true);                
        service.setUrl(new URI("https://legacy.server.country"));
        service.setTimeout(100*1000);


        EmailMessage msg= new EmailMessage(service);
        msg.setSubject("Test message "+System.currentTimeMillis()); 
        msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Sent using the EWS Managed API."));
        msg.getToRecipients().add("User@gmail.com");

        msg.send();
    }

    private static void testConnect() throws IOException {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket( 
                "mail.server.country",443);
        sslsocket.setUseClientMode(true);
        sslsocket.setSoTimeout(100000);
        sslsocket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new MyHandshakeListener());
        sslsocket.startHandshake();           
    }
    public static class MyHandshakeListener implements HandshakeCompletedListener {
        public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Handshake succesful!");
            System.out.println("Using cipher suite: " + e.getCipherSuite());
        }
    }

}
```

MS Exchange response:

> 403 Forbidden. The page requires a client certificate as part of the authentication process. If you are using a smart card, you will need to insert your smart card to select an appropriate certificate. Otherwise, contact your server administrator. (12213)

Handshake log:

```
counrtrycoden:
init Stores...
***
found key for : inertnal-signed-user-alias-key-bla-bla-bla
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=mycompuser, O=MYCOMP
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: BLABLABLA30690710815572912647945BLABLABLALABLA41197645359BLABLABLA883372709604731441625160BLABLABLA76697727043202584363067604BLABLABLA343388760502527327190704030612675772856546529931228983792825447712271
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Oct 25 09:44:41 MSK 2012,
               To: Mon Sep 01 15:04:44 MSK 2014]
  Issuer: CN=mycompany External CA, O=mycompany, C=counrtrycode
  SerialNumber: [    13bla267 00bla00 bla]

Certificate Extensions: 9
[1]: ObjectId: 1.bla13549.bla15 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 37 30 35 30 0E 06 08   2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 03 02  .7050...*.H.....
BLABLABLA


[2]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 28 30 26 30 0C 06 0A   2B 06 01 04 01 82 37 0A  .(0&0...+.....7.
BLABLABLA

[3]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 31 30BLABLABLA06   01 04 01 82 37 15 08 84  .10/.'+.....7...
0010: F3 D1 3C 87 F2 87 61 87   BD 9B BLABLABLA01 64  ..5.*...;...>..d
BLABLABLA

[4]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://pki.mycompany.counrtrycode/pki/aia/Cert01.glupka-and-tupka.mcmp.counrtrycode_mycompany%20External%20CA.crt
, 
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: ldap:///CN=mycompany%20External%20CA,CN=AIA,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=glupka-and-tupka,DC=mcmp,DC=counrtrycode?cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority
, 
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://extpki.glupka-and-tupka.mcmp.counrtrycode/CertEnroll/Cert01.glupka-and-tupka.mcmp.counrtrycode_mycompany%20External%20CA.crt
]
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: DB F3 38 88 08 D3 25 A2   D6 3E 5A C2 28 6D 21 09  ..8...%..>Z.(m!.
BLABLABLA
]
]

[6]: ObjectId: BLABLABLA.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://pki.mycompany.counrtrycode/pki/cdp/mycompany%20External%20CA.crl, URIName: ldap:///CN=mycompany%20External%20CA,CN=Cert01,CN=CDP,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=glupka-and-tupka,DC=mcmp,DC=counrtrycode?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint, URIName: http://extpki.glupka-and-tupka.mcmp.counrtrycode/CertEnroll/mycompany%20External%20CA.crl]
]]

[7]: ObjectId: BLABLABLA Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4
  emailProtection
  clientAuth
]

[8]: ObjectId: BLABLABLA Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
]

[9]: ObjectId: BLABLABLA Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: A4 AD 53 4BLABLABLA8   56 FB 4B 52 E3 09 AD 01  .BLABLABLA.KR....
BLABLABLA                                     X...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 9A C3 A3 3CBLABLABLAB9 80   8D F9 7CBLABLABLA8 11 EC  ...<.S......a...
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
SUPERLONGBLABLABLA
...
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
BLA0: DA 8FBLABLABLACC 96 B5   69 B2 BLABLABLADB 56  ...o`...i.V..h.V

]
***
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
=============BEGIN HANDSHAKE=============
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: tcounrtrycodee
Is initial handshake: tcounrtrycodee
Is secure renegotiation: false
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: tcounrtrycodee
Is initial handshake: tcounrtrycodee
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(100000) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1362721181 bytes = { 236, 175, 168, 239, 233, 179, 57, 191, 201, 185, 133, 27, 224, 105, 83, 227, 128, 210, 87, 189, 75, 234, 192, 181, 96, 94, 243, 25 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: services.mycompany.counrtrycode]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 174
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 5660
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1362721181 bytes = { 237, 63, 191, 247, 95, 109, 54, 253, 237, 198, 229, 127, 137, 49, 141, 141, 138, 20, 157, 117, 43, 124, 8, 94, 102, 171, 72, 136 }
Session ID:  {8, 30, 0, 0, 253, 200, 140, 197, 123, 73, 65, 166, 251, 106, 43, 119, 244, 46, 193, 144, 144, 57, 178, 24, 197, 204, 154, 63, 191, 102, 249, 105}
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=ol.mycompany.counrtrycode, OU=IT, O=mycompany, L=supercity, ST=counrtrycode, C=counrtrycode
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = BLA.2.BLABLA.BLA.49.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA890852115164310867BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA2675606906943672823219951400362124850736118214751967190281153250333278526809862357346858437645387972960703158481657469928478498122472555889883930655301090187944200780810614568244173675337773013453127652176661961716518027910113380649734092379900012537169502795030097799607532413142973889150997564045268730052023211864684133008169849100098476577268849374370540710200206831212156277099733103668127156062641899305BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Nov 15 08:56:19 MSK 2012,
               To: Mon Sep 01 15:04:44 MSK 2014]
  Issuer: CN=mycompany External CA, O=mycompany, C=counrtrycode
  SerialNumber: [    221f33ee 00000000 8011]

Certificate Extensions: 9
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.BLABLA311.21.10 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 0BLA06 08   2B BLA05 BLA3 01  ..BLA...+BLA....


[2]: ObjectId: BLABLA.1.311.21.7 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: BLA30 2F 06 27 2B 06   01 04 01 82BLA 08 84  .10/.'+.....7...
BLABLA                                      ...


[3]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://pki.mycompany.counrtrycode/pki/aia/Cert01.glupka-and-tupka.mcmp.counrtrycode_mycompany%20External%20CA.crt
, 
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: ldap:///CN=mycompany%20External%20CA,CN=AIA,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=glupka-and-tupka,DC=mcmp,DC=counrtrycode?cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority
, 
   accessMethod: ocsp
   accessLocation: URIName: http://extpki.glupka-and-tupka.mcmp.counrtrycode/CertEnroll/Cert01.glupka-and-tupka.mcmp.counrtrycode_mycompany%20External%20CA.crt
]
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: DB F3 38 88 08 D3 25 A2   D6 3E 5A C2 28 6D 21 09  ..8...%..>Z.(m!.
BLABLA                                       ....
]
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://pki.mycompany.counrtrycode/pki/cdp/mycompany%20External%20CA.crl, URIName: ldap:///CN=mycompany%20External%20CA,CN=Cert01,CN=CDP,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=glupka-and-tupka,DC=mcmp,DC=counrtrycode?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint, URIName: http://extpki.glupka-and-tupka.mcmp.counrtrycode/CertEnroll/mycompany%20External%20CA.crl]
]]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: services.mycompany.counrtrycode
  DNSName: autodiscover.mycompany.counrtrycode
  DNSName: post.mycompany.counrtrycode
]

[9]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 22 4D BLABLA 68 FB FA   94 BLABLAEE 12  "M.L.h...9Y.....
BLABLA
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 1C B5 34 B8 79 83 40 8F   65 0F 22 63 46 EC F5 C4  ..4.y.@.e."cF...
0010: 71 01 19 B1 2D 08 D5 0A   0E 5C 01 C4 68 A8 E9 7D  q...-....\..h...
0020: EC 29 65 F5 DD 7C C5 75   4F 51 D2 07 3D 14 44 E5  .)e....uOQ..=.D.
0030: E5 4E 7C 39 F3 50 CA 69   FF 44 3E 01 0F A7 BF BF  .N.9.P.i.D>.....
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
...
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
01F0: CB EF A7 1C 85 77 91 AF   AF 5C C3 E9 40 20 24 6E  .....w...\..@ $n

]
chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=mycompany External CA, O=mycompany, C=counrtrycode
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 4096 bits
  modulus: BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA98237839144558867BLABLA952659709867024101076930335BLABLA3611BLABLA3074298630BLABLA
  Validity: [From: Wed Sep 01 14:54:44 MSD 2010,
               To: Mon Sep 01 15:04:44 MSK 2014]
  Issuer: CN=mycompany Root CA, O=mycompany, C=counrtrycode
  SerialNumber: [    6BLABLAe5f 00000000 000a]

Certificate Extensions: 8
[1]: ObjectId: BLABLA.311.20.2 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 0BLABLAA 00 53 00 75   00 62 BLABLA3 00 41        .....S.u.b.C.A


[2]: ObjectId: BLABLA1.311.21.1 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04BLABLA1 00                                     .....


[3]: ObjectId: BLABLA7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://pki.mycompany.counrtrycode/pki/aia/mycompany%20Root%20CA.crt
, 
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: ldap:///CN=mycompany%20Root%20CA,CN=AIA,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=glupka-and-tupka,DC=mcmp,DC=counrtrycode?cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority
, 
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: ldap:///CN=mycompany%20Root%20CA,CN=AIA,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=ca,DC=mcmp,DC=counrtrycode?cACertificate?base?objectClass=certificationAuthority
, 
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://extpki.glupka-and-tupka.mcmp.counrtrycode/CertEnroll/rootca_mycompany%20Root%20CA.crt
, 
   accessMethod: caIssuers
   accessLocation: URIName: http://intpki.ca.mcmp.counrtrycode/CertEnroll/rootca_mycompany%20Root%20CA.crt
]
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 4BLABLAF2 BB 22   B0 DB 4E ACBLABLA85 20  A..@<.."..N.... 
0010: BLABLA 02                                        .*..
]
]

[5]: ObjectId: BLABLA.19 Criticality=tcounrtrycodee
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:tcounrtrycodee
  PathLen:0
]

[6]: ObjectId: BLABLA.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: http://pki.mycompany.counrtrycode/pki/cdp/mycompany%20Root%20CA.crl, URIName: ldap:///CN=mycompany%20Root%20CA,CN=rootca,CN=CDP,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=glupka-and-tupka,DC=mcmp,DC=counrtrycode?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint, URIName: ldap:///CN=mycompany%20Root%20CA,CN=rootca,CN=CDP,CN=Public%20Key%20Services,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=ca,DC=mcmp,DC=counrtrycode?certificateRevocationList?base?objectClass=cRLDistributionPoint, URIName: http://extpki.glupka-and-tupka.mcmp.counrtrycode/CertEnroll/mycompany%20Root%20CA.crl, URIName: http://intpki.ca.mcmp.counrtrycode/CertEnroll/mycompany%20Root%20CA.crl]
]]

[7]: ObjectId: BLABLA29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]

[8]: ObjectId: BLABLA.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: DB F3 38 88 08 D3 25 A2   D6 3E BLABLAD 21 09  ..8...%..>Z.(m!.
BLABLA                                        ....
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 62 85 DBLABLAA0 A9   74 3ABLABLA 78 3BLABLA 3A 93  b...h0..t:.x6Q:.
BLABLABLABLABLABLA
01F0: 06 D8 BLABLA 34   28 32 01 6A 4BLABLA E7 EC  ......r4BLABLA

]
***
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=CERTBServer, DC=glupka-and-tupka, DC=mcmp, DC=counrtrycode>
<CN=mycompany Root CA, O=mycompany, C=counrtrycode>
<OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US>
<CN=GTE CyberTcounrtrycodest Global Root, OU="GTE CyberTcounrtrycodest Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US>
<CN=Symantec Root CA, O=Symantec Corporation>
<CN=Microsoft Root Authority, OU=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Copyright (c) 1997 Microsoft Corp.>
<CN=Symantec Root 2005 CA, O=Symantec Corporation, C=US>
<CN=Microsoft Root Certificate Authority, DC=microsoft, DC=com>
<CN=NT AUTHORITY>
*** ServerHelloDone
*** Certificate chain
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 269
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 BLABLA 57 E5   32 68 13 0F BLABLAD C1 1B  ...BLABLA....
0010: 01 DE 2F FD C6 89 8B DF   24 55BLABLA8 DB 8A 2F  ../...BLABLA.(../
0020: A1 0BLABLA59 7A 5B   34 2BLABLA6 93 67 1D 43  .....BLABLA.g.C
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 51 39BLABLAA8 EF   E9 B3 39 BF BLABLA 85 1B  BLABLA9.....
0010: E0 69 53 BLABLA2 57 BD   4B EA C0 B5 60 5E F3 19  .iS.BLABLA..`^..
Server Nonce:
0000: 51 39 BLABLA ED 3F BF F7   5F 6DBLABLA C6 E5 7F  Q9z..BLABLA6.....
0010: 89 31 8D 8D 8A 14 9D 75   2B 7C 08 5E 66 AB 48 88  .1....BLABLA.H.
Master Secret:
0000: B5 3BLABLA02 45   BLABLA2A 21 49 B4  .8.BLABLA!I.
0010: DC E7BLABLA36 7E 4E 22   79 60 BLABLA75 CD 26  ....6.BLABLAu.&
0020: 2D 6BLABLAD2 1E 29   7EBLABLA7D 63 9E  -h..BLABLA...c.
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 38 BLABLAB 0D 91 8D   67 8BLABLA40 81  8.BLABLA..b@.
0010: 0D C5 4D D6                                        ..M.
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 42BLABLA 79 98   BD 57 50BLABLA D2 25 36  B..BLABLAPm..%6
0010: D4 8F E9 06                                        ....
Client write key:
0000: CBLABLAF 76 82   31 06 3FBLABLA41 6D  ....BLABLA..Am
Server write key:
0000: 1BLABLABLABLA F3   A1 3BLABLABLABLA 24  .BLABLA...<.BLABLA.$
Client write IV:
0000: BLABLA3 28 09   AD 68 AD 1BLABLA7 76 86  .(.BLABLA.h..ugv.
Server write IV:
0000: BLABLAC 8F E2 CC   EA 5A BLABLA1 BC BD BC  BLABLA.....
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { BLA, 165, 142, 254, 222, BLA, 58, 72, BLA, 131, 19, 122 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 73, BLA, 110, BLA, 55, 62, BLA, 155, 179, BLA, 90, 19 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
>Handshake succesful!
Using cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

Comment: That's not the complete handshake log. You've left out the most important part, starting where the server sends the CertificateRequest, and the client's response if any. Please edit that into your question.

Comment: My env: Ubuntu 12.04, Java 1.7.0_17  (due to EWSJavaAPI 1.2 dependency)

Comment: >keytool -list -v -keystore myfile.pfx -storetype pkcs12 =
Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: inertnal-signed-user-alias-key-bla-bla-bla 
Creation date: Mar 32, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to implementation of EWSJavaAPI and my own necessity ot use client-certificate  for two-way-auth appeared together.

First we should correctly init context.
EWSJavaAPI uses apache commons HttpClient 3.1 that is no more supported , moved to another package httpcomponents. But we use legacy and it looks like working. 
We init SSlContext, then make SSL socket factory, and register Protocol with this factory.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");            
ks.load(new FileInputStream("cert.pfx"),"pass".toCharArray());

System.out.println("init Stores...");

ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(new KeyManager[] { new MyKeyManager(ks, "pass") }, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());                       
SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

ProtocolSocketFactory psf = new SSLProtocolSocketFactory();   
Protocol https = new Protocol("https", psf, 443);
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", https);
```

where MyKeyManager looks like:

```
public class MyKeyManager extends X509ExtendedKeyManager {

    KeyStore keystore = null;
    String password = null;
    public MyKeyManager(KeyStore keystore, String password) {
        this.keystore = keystore;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String chooseClientAlias(String[] arg0, Principal[] arg1, Socket arg2) {
        return ""; // can't be null
    }

    @Override
    public String chooseServerAlias(String arg0, Principal[] arg1, Socket arg2) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String arg0) {
        try {
            X509Certificate[] result = new X509Certificate[keystore.getCertificateChain(keystore.aliases().nextElement()).length];
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                result[i] = (X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificateChain(keystore.aliases().nextElement())[i];
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getClientAliases(String arg0, Principal[] arg1) {
        try {
            return new String[] { keystore.aliases().nextElement() };
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String arg0) {
        try {
            return ((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keystore.getEntry(keystore.aliases().nextElement(),
                new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password.toCharArray()))).getPrivateKey();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getServerAliases(String arg0, Principal[] arg1) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

During EmailMessage.send()  we are going to microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.HttpClientWebRequest .
And ... surprise:

```
@Override
public void prepareConnection() throws EWSHttpException {
    // ...
    Protocol.registerProtocol("https", 
            new Protocol("https", new EwsSSLProtocolSocketFactory(), 443));
    // ...
}
```

We re-register socket factory, and our certs will never be populated. Let see what is EwsSSLProtocolSocketFactory:

```
public EwsSSLProtocolSocketFactory() {
    super();
}

private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() {
    try {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        context.init(
            null, 
            new TrustManager[] {new EwsX509TrustManager(null, trustManager)}, 
            null);
        return context;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()+e);
        throw new HttpClientError(e.toString());
    }
}

private SSLContext getSSLContext() {
    if (this.sslcontext == null) {
        this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
    }
    return this.sslcontext;
}
```

Super easily created SSLContext will be used. It does not allow to use own keys , only checking trusted certs and only from default /usr/local/java/1.7.X/../cacerts .

Fortunately, sources are provided and for the first time we could comment "Protocol.registerProtocol" and it solves a problem.